# Is IRK in android can be referred as unique and stable ID?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use ble in my system and connect with it to android app. I need to have unique ID of the smartphone for future connection and I understood that the bt device address in android is not stable and changed with time, so I can't use this as a unique ID of the connection. I found out that there is a key called IRK, I would like to know if it can be referred to as unique ID and also as a stable ID and not anything that randomly generated every few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The IRK is supposed to be stable. The only time I've seen it be recreated is at a major Android update (6 to 7 or something) but that was probably due to a bug and not intended.

Since IRK is used for bonded devices to identify each other, a user would need to re-bond if an IRK gets changed, which is why the IRK is never changed.

Comment: How do you get the IRK on Android?

Comment: It's distributed when a BLE pairing is performed to the remote device, using the protocol defined by the Bluetooth standard. There is no API or so to get it for the local device on Android if you for some strange reason would like to get it that way.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion some time ago that the IRK was not available but its nice to have confirmation. I submitted a request to Android some time ago to make it accessible but it clearly fell on deaf ears. Because Android does not handle the IRK correctly it barfs on a bonded reconnect with devices using resolvable random addressing. At least I have not been able to get it work.